# How to enforce upload photo from camera

Tags: javascript, html

My Web application target is allow user to upload a picture from camera and guarantee that the picture is NOT been selected from user archive.

The following code work fine but user can choose if "Take a picture" or "Select a picture". Is it possible to force only "Take a picture" option?

```
<input id="myFileInput" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
<script>
var myInput = document.getElementById('myFileInput');

function sendPic() {
    var file = myInput.files[0];

    // Send file here 

}

myInput.addEventListener('change', sendPic, false);
</script>
```

Any other idea?

Answer (score 3):

There was an approach to do this via the [`navigator.getUserMedia()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia), but that is in danger of becomming deprecated and it wasn't supported in Safari and Webkit.

There is a new standard for doing this, with [`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(myConstraints)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), but it is not supported widely yet (no support in IE and Safari).

Until we have a consistently implemented API, JavaScript will not be able to accomplish this. What you need is a native app that can access the phone's functionality, which JavaScript can't do.

Answer (score -1):

Accessing the camera from the browser with javascript has been possible since 2012. See [caniuse getUserMedia()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream): it is supported by 70% of used browsers. Are you only intrested in mobile devices? Then the percentage is higher.

The method was defined as navigator.getUserMedia() first, but has since moved to MediaDevices.getUserMedia().

To use getUserMedia() to generate just one picture (as opposed to a video stream) 
follow this [Tutorial on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos) and it's [demo](https://mdn-samples.mozilla.org/s/webrtc-capturestill/), it does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia This has been deprecated. This is the new standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia but it is not supported widely.

Comment: navigator.getUserMedia has been deprecated. the new method is MediaDevices.getUserMedia().  you can check it by trying out the demo contained in the tutorial

Comment: The new method is not supported in IE and Safari, so it is not very practical.

Comment: there is a big difference between "not possible" and "not supported by a tiny percentage of mobile browsers"

Comment: My answer has been updated. Also, do you think that Safari represents a tiny percentage of mobile browsers?

Comment: For the year 2016, the desktop browsers that this won't work on was 36% and the mobile browsers it won't work on is just over 30%. https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=0&qptimeframe=Y&qpcustomd=1

Comment: Could be, but SO is about providing responses that are useful in the real world.

Comment: yep. and not for long discussions.